# Selenium does not install add-on in Firefox when using the addExtensions option

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, geckodriver

I want to install a custom XPI file in Firefox when running it with `selenium` and `geckodriver` in a TypeScript and Jest context.

The important part of the test script [is this](https://github.com/slhck/web-extension-selenium-test/blob/master/test/integration/setupSimpleTest.test.ts#L14):

```js
let driver: webdriver.WebDriver;
const firefoxExt = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..', 'extension', 'firefox.xpi');
const firefoxOptions = new firefox.Options().addExtensions(firefoxExt);
driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('firefox').setFirefoxOptions(firefoxOptions).build();
```

I am expecting Firefox to launch and install firefox.xpi as an add-on, but there are no add-ons present in the opened Firefox instance. There is no issue with the XPI itself, as the XPI can be installed manually, as a temporary extension, without issues. Also, the XPI exists at the path, as otherwise it would error out on `path.resolve`.

For others to reproduce the issue, I have created a repository with a minimal, reproducible example. See this repo: https://github.com/slhck/web-extension-selenium-test

Note that this is not a duplicate of:

- [Cannot load extension using firefox driver selenium when using AddExtension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57778036/cannot-load-extension-using-firefox-driver-selenium-when-using-addextension) (unanswered, closed)
- [How to install extension permanently in geckodriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54754945/how-to-install-extension-permanently-in-geckodriver) (I do not want a permanent install, as the XPI will be changed before the test suite runs)
- [How to load extension within chrome driver in selenium with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50443955/how-to-load-extension-within-chrome-driver-in-selenium-with-python) (I am already using `addExtension`)

I have created a [bug report](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/8285) in Selenium itself, but it has not received any activity yet.

Does anyone know what the issue could be, and how it could be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `installAddon`. There may be a more elegant way to do this, but the code below works:

```
beforeAll(async () => {
  const firefoxExt = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..', 'extension', 'firefox.xpi');
  driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('firefox').build();
  new firefox.Driver(driver.getSession(), driver.getExecutor()).installAddon(firefoxExt, true);
});
```

Comment: IWebDriver.InstallAddon does not exist in the C# API - any ideas?